# homepage background sliding images (Android)

Tags: android, user-interface, background, handler, sliding

Is there an alternative way to ViewPager for implementing automatic sliding of background images in the Main fragment(Homepage) ? Have it switch the background every X seconds automatically.

Comment: you can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and move viewpager programatically for every X seconds

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Is it activity-coupled? I mean, if the app quits or even crashes, that `ScheduledExecutorService` is killed as well right ? (basically, I'm asking if it uses a separate thread of the activity's thread).

Also I've been having some OutOfMemory excpetions with my current implementation on some devices, majority of them are old devices. Perhaps the size of the images was too big(?) , could you recommend a way to tackle this issue? perhaps by using 3party libraries like Picaso.( Though it's better not to use any 3party libs)